# Can we ask about the safety of a script or executable?

Tags: discussion

I am searching for a vpn and came across this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/705576/158636)  and this [github](https://github.com/sbandur84/Free-OpenVPN-Connect-for-Linux) site. I dont know whether the bash script `FreeVPNconnect.sh` is secure or not, that is whether it is a malicious script or not. Can I  ask in this SE to authenticate the safety of a script? Or what other SE will you recommend to ask this type of question?

Comment: You really can't ever ask about a script hosted elsewhere, because after someone reviewed it and posted an answer saying it was ok, the content could be changed by the owner of the site hosting it.

At a minimum, one would have to identify a particular version of the script, by either making a complete copy or taking a cryptographically strong hash.

Comment: @BenVoigt As long as you trust GitHub, [this](https://github.com/sbandur84/Free-OpenVPN-Connect-SCRIPT-for-Linux/blob/65fb39d4c2cd6eb05898fa9e60b60736e67015e4/FreeVPNconnect.sh) should be a good enough "hash".